# download disconnects and web server log shows 404

Tags: apache, google-chrome, download, proxy, resume

Imagine an Internet speed of 20KB/s and a 20MB file. It takes 1000 seconds to download the file completely.
Using proxies like browsec, download fails at the middle of it. each time, after a random seconds. In these situations, Web server log (server is apache) indicates a **404** error. (problem **1**)
I thought 404 means **file doesn't exist**. Doesn't it?  but the file exists and some percents of it (again, random percents. once 50%, once 20% ...) is downloaded.
I don't really know what is happening between the proxy and the server. But I am sure that the browser doesn't show a **failed** text as it seems the file downloaded completely.

Downloading the file directly without any proxies, there is no problem and it downloads completely. But **Chrome** doesn't have resume capability, while **Firefox** does. really why chrome doesn't resume the download? (problem **2**)

Any help about these two problems is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are noticing 404 in apache access logs then its the apache that is telling that the file is not present to browser and nothing to do with proxy server or browser. May be in certain scenarios the incoming request is appended with query parameters or character encoding which is making apache to respond 404. Very hard to tel without having a look at logs.

Comment: Dear @Vinod , Thanks for your reply. Yes, apache shows **404** in the web server log, while the file exists and I am sure that some percents of it( i.e 70% of the file) has been downloaded. Since apache saves logs after finishing the request, it shows **404** for the corrupted downloads and that's why I have posted a question here. Here is a sample log file: (just replaced the IP)
**abc.abc.abc.abc - - [25/Aug/2015:04:02:58 -0700] "GET /download/?n=book-1&f=pdf HTTP/1.0" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.5; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)"**

Comment: I noticed that when I start downloading a file from the server, and then abort it manually, although the file exists, server saves the log status as **404**. so the possibility that something is going wrong with proxies and the server which drops the connection became stronger to me. Any help or idea? thanks.